# Calculus I Differentiate $(\cos (2x))^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate the following problem:

$$
\cos^2(2x)
$$

From my understanding it differentiates to $-4\cos(2x)\sin(2x)$ but I'm not sure how it got to this.  I'm not sure where the $\cos (2x)$ comes from.

Can someone step me through this problem?

Comment: Let $u=\cos2x$; use the chain rule

Comment: that's what I'm confused about ... if I use chain rule I get -4sin(2x)

Answer (score 1):

It will be clearer, I hope, using Leibniz' notation to differentiate a composition of functions:
$$\frac{\mathrm d(\cos^2 2x)}{\mathrm d x} =\frac{\mathrm d(\cos^2 2x)}{\mathrm d(\cos 2x)}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d(\cos 2x)}{\mathrm d(2x)}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d(\ 2x)}{\mathrm d x }=2\cos 2x\cdot(-\sin 2x)\cdot 2 =-2\sin 4x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(u)=u^2$ and $g(x)=\cos(2x)$, so $f'(u)=2u$ and $g'(x)=-2\sin 2x$.

By the chain rule, $\dfrac d{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)=(2\color{green}{\cos2x})(-2\sin2x)=-4\cos2x\sin2x.$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:
\begin{align}
& y = u^2 & & u = \cos v & v=2x. \\[10pt]
& \frac{dy}{du} = 2u & & \frac{du}{dv} = -\sin v & \frac{dv}{dx} = 2 \\[10pt] {}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = 2u\cdot(-\sin v)\cdot2 \\[10pt]
& = 2\big(\cos(2x)\big)\cdot(-\sin(2x\big) \cdot 2.
\end{align}